# Numbers for Testing Integer Factoring Algorithms

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization

I'm looking for a list of numbers with which to test an integer factorization algorithm (for a computer). Something that has numbers harder than the ones I could easily come up with. Do any resources like this exist?

I'm not talking state-of-the-art-algorithm-with-a-supercomputer-and-the-university-pays-the-electricity-bill hard... just a nice range of test problems ranging from easy-peazy to ones that should take a few minutes with a decent algorithm on a decent computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply two $n$ digit primes and then ask your algorithm to factor the result. Increase $n$ as far as you like.

Mathematica (Wolfram Alpha) will find primes for you

[image]